# Creating a Datamart with GitHub information

Tags: analytics, etl, data-warehouse, amazon-kinesis-firehose, datamart

I would like to create a Datamart with GitHub information with commits, pull requests, reverts and so on.

GitHub provides many webhooks with these events. I am trying to create an architecture to process these events and load it to a RDS Database.

I was thinking in use a API Gateway + Kinesis Firehose to dump the events to the S3.  Then use a cron (like. https://airflow.apache.org/) to process these files.

Cons and Pros:

(+)  It's reliable as we have a simple API Gateway + Kineses dumping to S3.

(+) It's easy to reprocess as I am using Airflow

(-) It seems a little bit over architecting

(-) It will not be a real-time datamart.

Do u guys can think and propose another architecture with PROS and CONS?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with:

```
API Gateway -> Lambda -> Kinesis Stream -> Kinesis Analytics
```

This will give you the requirement of being real-time.

You can then offload the streams to S3 using Kinesis Firehose for any ad-hoc querying.